# Is it possible to write directly on a block device while it is mounted by a filesystem?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Let's say i have a block device that has been mounted by a file system, from what i understand that block device cannot be mounted again.

But is it possible, from user space, to call an "open" on it and write on it directly? Or does the mount prevent any other open from happening?

If it is like this, how does the file system write on it? Does it keep the information of the open that it did with the mount?

Comment: I'd ask this under serverfault. However, yes, it is possible to write onto /dev/sda1 while it is mounted. This will most probably destroy the file system. And, no, the block device can be opened multiple times. If you set up an ISCSI server, multiple nodes may mount /dev/sda1 and they need a cluster file system for correct locking then.

If you want to destroy your file system /dev/sdx1 for example, the command would be dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdx1. You need to be root, but it's in the user space.

The file system writes onto it using syscalls, e.g. fwrite, after opening with e.g. fopen

Comment: Why not test it? `how does the file system write on it?` ? What do you mean by "how"? Just like anything else. `Does it keep the information of the open that it did with the mount?` File system is written in the kernel, it can "use" the disc, not the block device.

Comment: Yes you can "open("/dev/xxx", ...)" and write into it through the returned file descriptor. But unless you know exactly what you are modifying that it to say unless you know the exact mapping of the data stored in the file system, you are pretty sure to corrupt the file system.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk you could probably turn your comment into an answer.